# jsonapi.org standard with Realm Android

Tags: android, realm, json-api

I want to parse json that follow   [jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org/) standard

I am using [jsonapi-converter](https://github.com/jasminb/jsonapi-converter)  for converter and want to implement Realm as well. I couldnt get any ideas or clue how to implement both. If any one had done it your help will be appreciated alot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can classes using jsonapi-converter extend RealmObject and use annotations of Realm? If it is possible, they could be mixed together. Otherwise, I think you should convert jsonapi-converter objects to JsonObject, JSON string or Realm Object.

Comment: @Dalinaum i am working on it. Using jsonapi-converter i could parse and extend RealmObject but about realm annotation i am testing  on it.

Comment: It's best practice to keep the API response and the database objects separate, in that case it really isn't a question how to do both.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you mean to say is response object and realm object should be separate??? For example if i am getting user datas then response and database object can be same as User. I guess.

Comment: Hey @ArjunGurung, where are we on this?  If you have a solution, would you share it?

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike ok i will be posting in anser

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike check my answer

Comment: That looks like it should work to me.  I'm guessing that, e.g., `GlobalUtils.getMap` turns a `com.github.jasminb.jsonapi.Links` into a `RealmList<JsonMap>` and that you need both objects, for some reason.  If you either didn't need the `Links` object, or if it were a subclass of RealmObject this would be simpler, as @Dalinaum and @EpicPandaForce point out.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike `GlobalUtils.getMap` turns a `com.github.jasminb.jsonapi.Links` into a `RealmList<JsonMap>`. But i think there might be other better solutions in case these link and list migration. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "type":"product",
         "id":"1",
         "attributes":{
            "title":"Wai Wai Noodles",
            "description":"",
            "liked":true,
            "is-active":true
         },
         "links":{
            "self":"https://wongel.info/product/1"
         },
         "relationships":{
            "productinfo":{
               "links":{
                  "self":"https://wongel.info/product/1/relationships/productinfo",
                  "related":"https://wongel.info/product/1/productinfo"
               },
               "data":{
                  "type":"productinfo",
                  "id":"1"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "included":[
      {
         "type":"productinfo",
         "id":"1",
         "attributes":{
            "product-category":null,
            "description":null
         },
         "links":{
            "self":"https://wongel.info/productinfo/1"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This is my json i have to parse following jsonApi.Org standard. I am using 
[jasminb/jsonapi-converter](https://github.com/jasminb/jsonapi-converter)
 for parsing with realm. So Here are my Product class and Prodct info class

```
@Type("product")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Product extends RealmObject {
    @Id
    @PrimaryKey
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;
    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;
    @JsonProperty("is_active")
    private boolean isActive;
    @JsonProperty("liked")
    private boolean liked;

    @Relationship("productinfo")
    private ProductInfo productInfo;

    @Ignore
    @Links
    @JsonProperty("links")
    private com.github.jasminb.jsonapi.Links links;
    @JsonIgnore
    private RealmList<JsonMap> linkList;

    @Ignore
    @RelationshipLinks("productinfo")
    private com.github.jasminb.jsonapi.Links productLinks;
    @JsonIgnore
    private RealmList<JsonMap> productLinkList;

    //setter getter

    public void migrateToList() {
        linkList = GlobalUtils.getMap(links);
        productLinkList = GlobalUtils.getMap(productLinks);
    }

    public void migrateToLink() {
        links = GlobalUtils.getMap(linkList);
        productLinks = GlobalUtils.getMap(productLinkList);
    }
}
```

ProductInfo

```
@Type("productinfo")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ProductInfo extends RealmObject {
    @Id
    @PrimaryKey
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty("product-category")
    private String category;
    @JsonProperty("description")
    private String description;

//setter getter
}
```

JsonMap for saving link datas

```
public class JsonMap extends RealmObject {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public JsonMap() {

    }

    public JsonMap(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

So Once reading docs of jasminb/jsonapi-converter you will understand how it is working. Tricky part is realm need all its object extend realmObject or realmModule i tried overiding Link and Links in jasminb/jsonapi-converter didnt work so what i did is seen in Product model. There are 2 classes

```
public void migrateToList() {
        linkList = GlobalUtils.getMap(links);
        productLinkList = GlobalUtils.getMap(productLinks);
    }

    public void migrateToLink() {
        links = GlobalUtils.getMap(linkList);
        productLinks = GlobalUtils.getMap(productLinkList);
    }
```

One helps to migrate data from link to realmList which supported by realm and another from list to link which is needed for calling apis etc.

```
ResourceConverter converter = new ResourceConverter(ProductR.class, ProductInfo.class);
        converter.enableSerializationOption(SerializationFeature.INCLUDE_RELATIONSHIP_ATTRIBUTES);

        JSONAPIConverterFactory converterFactory = new JSONAPIConverterFactory(converter);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
                .build();
        ApiService apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

        Call<JSONAPIDocument<List<Product>>> call = apiService.getProducts();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONAPIDocument<List<Product>>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONAPIDocument<List<Product>>> call, Response<JSONAPIDocument<List<Product>>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // success
                } else {
                    //error body
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONAPIDocument<List<Product>>> call, Throwable t) {
                //failed
            }
        });
```

Above code for calling server api.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly everyone who has reviewed this code (including me, @Dalinaum and @EpicPandaForce) suggests, immediately, that you separate the JSON and Realm representations: Read the JSON into a JSON object and add either a `toRealm` method on the JSON object, or a `fromJson` method (or a constructor) on the Realm object.

Attempting to represent both external interfaces in the same object ties the two representation together and is probably not good separation of concerns.

We all agree that what you are doing is clever and will work.  We all suggest that you do it differently!

Comment: Doing so will definitely separate ties between realm and json but doing so it will lead into creating many models. So is that better having more model class then tying it together? I will try it once though. Thanks for your review.